# How to remove all new lines characters '\n' and format the script

Tags: shell

I've script content like this example and I need to remove all '\n' and format the script is regular format instead of wrapped lines.

```
#\n# Copyright (c) 2012   2016 by ABC. All rights reserved.\n#\n# This script handles the creation of database on a server.\n# Using db utility we are creating db for emp\n# db settings\n# we are starting the database.\n\n#\n# Program Name ...\n#\nPGM_NAME='createDB.sh'\n\n#\n#
```

I tried using substring in VI editor like this but did not format the script.

```
:%s/\n//g
```

Comment: What is "regular format"?

Comment: Do you mean "replace literal `\n` with linebreaks"?

Comment: Why not simply `printf "$(<script)" > formatted_script` ??

Answer (score 0):

In vi regex, you need to escape backslashes and literal control characters. To escape backslashes you double them; to escape control characters, you precede them by <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>.

So, to replace `\n` with newlines, you can do:

`:%s/\\n/`<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>CTRL-M</kbd>`/g`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a `printf` or `echo -e` with a *command substitution* to output the formatted script that can then be redirected to a new file if you choose? For example: `printf "$(<script)"` or `echo -e $(<script)`

You don't want to *remove* the newline characters, you want to *expand* the escape sequence.

**Example Use/Output**

With your original single-line in the file names `script`:

```
$ printf "$(<script)"
#
# Copyright (c) 2012   2016 by ABC. All rights reserved.
#
# This script handles the creation of database on a server.
# Using db utility we are creating db for emp
# db settings
# we are starting the database.

#
# Program Name ...
#
PGM_NAME='createDB.sh'

#
#
```

(the results with `echo -e $(<script)` are the same but it adds an additional `'\n'` at the end -- which may be preferable -- up to you)

You can redirect the result to a new file of your choosing to capture the formatted script.